# How to upload a file using http PUT with httpie?

Tags: curl, http, upload

For some webserver testing, I use curl for file upload like this:

```
$ curl --silent --digest --user user:pass --upload-file filename http://server/dir/
```

Now I tried to archive the same function but with usage of httpie. Tried something like:

```
$ http --auth-type digest --auth user:pass PUT http://server/dir/
```

but cannot find a parameter to pass a filename for upload. Trying e.g. this

```
$ http --auth-type digest --auth user:pass PUT http://server/dir/ A=B
```

has the consequence that the content `{"A": "B"}` will be passed as http request body,
but I want to pass the raw content of a (maybe binary) file as request body instead (like possible with curl).

Might there be a way to do this also using httpie?

(I'd tested with httpie 0.9.2 on Kubuntu 16.04 host.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, digging deeper into httpie documentation, finding out that there are 2 ways to pass raw body data.

Either by piping or input redirection. httpie reads the body data from stdin:

```
$ cat filename | http --auth-type digest --auth user:pass PUT http://server/dir/filename
```

or

```
$ http --auth-type digest --auth user:pass PUT http://server/dir/filename <filename
```

or using that `@` parameter like this:

```
$ http --auth-type digest --auth user:pass PUT http://server/dir/filename @filename
```

See also:

- https://httpie.org/doc#request-data-from-a-filename
- https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie/issues/534
- https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie/issues/489